# How to use insertBefore() without second parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

In [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp) example says that second parameter for insertBefore() method is optional:

> The child node you want to insert the new node before. When not
>   specified, the insertBefore method will insert the newnode at the end.

My code:

```js
let li = document.createElement('LI');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Water"));
let list = document.getElementById('list');
list.insertBefore(li);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

But when I try to use insertBefore with one parameter I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2
>   arguments required, but only 1 present.

But this code work correctly:

```
list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this example says that second parameter for insertBefore() method is optional:

It's incorrect, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) or [the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-insertbefore) (though frankly that current spec is much harder to follow than [the old one](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727)). (Unfortunately, accuracy and completeness are ongoing issues with w3schools, strongly recommend using MDN instead.) You can use `null` as the second argument, but you must provide it:

```js
let li = document.createElement('LI');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Water"));
let list = document.getElementById('list');
list.insertBefore(li, null);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

w3schools is wrong yet again. MDN is much more reliable:

[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

> referenceNode is not an optional parameter -- you must explicitly pass a Node or null. Failing to provide it or passing invalid values may behave differently in different browser versions.